# Is there a sleep function for C# without bugging out my Visual Studio 2022 app UI?

Tags: c#, wait, sleep, thread-sleep, visual-studio-2022

I have been looking all over Stack Overflow, Google and W3schools and didn't find a sleep or wait function which doesn't bug out my UI.

`Task.Wait` or `Task.Delay` both bug out my UI by replacing every object with a white rectangle.

Here's the code:

```cs
Task t = Task.Run(async delegate
    {
        OS.label1.Text = Translation.EN_US.SetupLoading;
        centerLabel(OS.label1);
        await Task.Delay(20000);
        return 42;
    });
```

*Note: I am a beginner programmer who's been programming for 3 years*

Comment: Have you tried running a `repair` on your Visual Studio installation? You can also try uninstalling it and re-installing the application.

Comment: Are you referring to the UI of the application you're building, or the UI of Visual Studio itself?  Can you provide a [mcve] demonstrating the issue?

Comment: This is a great question. But unfortunately, you need to handle threading in this matter as the UI Thread not delayed/sleeping is very important for smooth rendering of your UI. So you need to study Threading, and the use of Background Threads.

A good architecture is for the UI to send signals to worker engine(thread) that sits on the background and executes work. The UI would then just listen to updates from the worker engine and periodically show updates in the UI. 

There are many ways to handle the signalling between the UI thread and the background thread. see https://reactivex.io/

Comment: Hi David, I'm meaning the UI of my application.

Comment: So you are blocking the UI thread. We can't tell why without seeing some code.

Comment: I'm guessing you are not using `Task.Delay` correctly, you want to do `await Task.Delay` not `Task.Delay.Wait`

Comment: Hi Charlie, I am using Task.Delay correctly.

Comment: I'd question why you want to 'sleep' in the first place?

Comment: I am building a fictional OS, so I'd want it to simulate taking the time to load.

Comment: it's unbelievable that  you're building an OS!

Comment: `Task.Run` will start your code on a background thread, so you won't be able to directly access or modify any controls from that task.